# Time passed from a specific date

Tags: datetime

I would like to put in my resume

> N years experience in Java

where N would be generated based on the date provided in the LaTeX file.

Preferably in rounded years, i.e. If the beginning date was 2012-06-04 and the output was generated on 2014-04-04, then the N would be 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A macro using the function defined in my answer to [Day of the year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121360/day-of-the-year)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\roundyears}{mmm}
 {% #1 = year, #2 = month, #3 = day (beginning of experience
  \fp_eval:n
   {
    floor (
     ( \juliandate_calc:nnnn { \day } { \month } { \year } { \use:n }
      -
      \juliandate_calc:nnnn { #3 } { #2 } { #1 } { \use:n } ) / 365
    )
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \juliandate_calc:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 % #1 = day, #2 = month, #3 = year, #4 = what to do
 {
  #4
   {
    \int_eval:n
     {
      #1 +
      \int_div_truncate:nn
       {
        153 * (#2 + 12 * \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } - 3) + 2
       }
       { 5 } +
      365 * (#3 + 4800 - \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } ) +
      \int_div_truncate:nn { #3 + 4800 - \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } } { 4 } -
      \int_div_truncate:nn { #3 + 4800 - \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } } { 100 } +
      \int_div_truncate:nn { #3 + 4800 - \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } } { 400 } -
      32045
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\roundyears{2011}{05}{06}

\roundyears{2012}{05}{03}

\roundyears{2012}{07}{12}

\end{document}
```

[image]